# Unsubscribe from Rethink DB Outside function in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Im using Socket.io and Rethink DB to push realtime data on Node.js.
Subscribing to the stream works but when the user disconnects I can figure out how to unsubscribe to the rethink db.

Here's my code:

Part of app.js:

```
// Adding socket.io
app.io = require('socket.io')();
var feed;
// On connection to the socket, just invoking the function.
app.io.on('connection',function(socket) {
  console.log('Client connected...');
  feed = require('./feed')(socket);
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('Got disconnect!');

      # Here I'd like to unsubscribe

   });
});
```

feed.js:

```
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var dbConfig = require('./config/database');
module.exports = function(socket) {
  var connection = r.connect(dbConfig)
  .then(function (connection) {

    r.db('Minicall').table('Message').changes().run(connection,function(err,cursor) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      cursor.each(function(err,row) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
        if(Object.keys(row).length > 0) {
          console.log("send");
          socket.emit("msgFeed",{"timestamp" : row.new_val.timestamp, "message" : row.new_val.message ,"ric" : row.new_val.ric});
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

So, how can I stop the subscribing (connection.stop()) when socket.on('disconnect') gets called? Probably a easy solution since I'm totally new to node and js.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one event listener to an event, so in your cursor you'll add a disconnect event listener that can call `cursor.close()`:

```
r.db('Minicall')
.table('Message')
.changes()
.run(connection, function(err, cursor) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  cursor.each(function(err,row) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    if(Object.keys(row).length > 0) {
      console.log("send");
      socket.emit("msgFeed",{"timestamp" : row.new_val.timestamp, "message" : row.new_val.message ,"ric" : row.new_val.ric});
    }
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    cursor.close();
  });
});
```